# Converting a Java Web Application to a Jar Independent of a Browser

Tags: java, applet, jnlp

I have a huge java web application that seems to have a quite complicated structure. It is an applet (as it runs as an applet on the browser...)

Also it has all the HTML relevant code of an applet.

I am using Netbeans and have set it up as a "Java Web Application".

Now I want to convert this to a jar.

I am planning to use this (if you know any other way please let me know):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet_migration.html#advantages

Here is the HTML file:

```
<applet code = "AppletApp" 
codebase = "<%=context%>/" 
archive = "<%=context%>/appletApp.jar,<%=context%>/other.jar" 
width = "100%" height = "100%" align = "baseline" mayscript = "true">
</applet>
```

Now using the guide above as far as I understood there are 2 options:

1. Migrating an Existing Java Applet

and

2. Re-writing a Java Applet as a Java Web Start Application

I don't know how to do point 1 in Netbeans since I have a number of `<resources>` tags and I do not know which to convert. Point 2 seems more promising for me.

So AppleApp.java has the applet method `init()` that I will be replacing with main.

This is what is a bit confusing for me:

"*To quickly begin the migration, you can just add the main method to your original applet class, and then start calling your applet initialization code where it normally gets called from the applet's init and start methods. Once there is a main method in the applet class, you can begin launching it by means of Java Web Start technology, and then slowly remove the dependency on the Applet class and convert it completely to your application's main class.*"

SO I will remove the old methods, I will just add main and copy paste whatever cose I had in `init()` ?

Also what do they mean by this: "*you can begin launching it by means of Java Web Start technology*".

I tried running `javac ....`on AppletApp since it has a main method and I got errors related to not finding certain classes. I wanted to try to put all classes in the same folder and changing the code a bit. I don't know if that will work..

Also this app was developed with Java 1.3, and is running with Java 1.8